# Xcode second target gives Cannot Run Using Selected Device or Dead Bootstrap Subset

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I am having an issue where I cannot get a second target in my Xcode project to run (using Xcode 5.1.1).

I have checked the Schemes and they appear to be identical except they each point to their own proper executable .app (as they should). The excecutable name matches the Product Name in Build Settings.

I checked Build Settings to make sure they each were pointing to individual Info.plist files (target1-Info.plist and target2-Info.plist). The second target has a different Target name, different Bundle ID and different Product Name from the first target.

In order to get the first target to run, I had to follow this post: [Xcode 5 cannot run using selected device on iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225327/xcode-5-cannot-run-using-selected-device-on-ios-simulator)

However the second target will still not run in the simulator and I will get one of the following errors:

Either I get this error which says `Xcode cannot run using the selected device`

[image: Cannot run using selected device]

Or I get the following message that appears in the debug area at the bottom of Xcode which says `Dead bootstrap subset` and `Error spawning child process: Permission denied`

[image: Dead bootstrap subset Error spawning child process permission denied]

Now if I archive both targets for iOS this gives an additional hint as to what the problem might be...

When I Archive Target 1, it takes about 15 to 20 seconds to build and archive and generates a 43MB estimated file size (this archive is correct).

But when I try to Archive Target 2, it takes about 1 second to build and archive and generates a 5MB estimated file size with a blank white icon. Target 2 should be the same 43MB file size as Target 1, so clearly something somewhere in Xcode is confused and causing Target 2 to not archive properly (which would explain why it is not running in the simulator).

Also the other thing I noticed is under Build Settings, Target 2 is missing all the Apple LLVM sections and I tried to get them to appear but cannot.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming that both targets were working fine at one time, and now one of them will no longer run, I basically duplicated the working target and deleted the non-working one like this:

- Rename the bad Target name to something like BadTarget.
- Rename the bad Scheme name to something like BadScheme.
- Duplicate the good working target.
- Rename this new duplicated target to something like NewTarget.
- Change the Bundle ID, Bundle Name, Bundle Display Name and Product name of this new target.
- Rename the new scheme that was created when you duplicated the target to something like NewScheme.
- Test run the original working target and the new duplicated target to make sure they both work.
- Make any other changes to new duplicated target Build Settings that are unique in the bad target. For example, I define a variable FreeApp or PaidApp in the Apple LLVM Preprocessor section to identify which target is the free/lite version versus the paid/full version.
- Delete the bad Target.
- Delete the bad Scheme.

I would hope somebody comes up with an easier solution, but this is the only workaround I could come up with.